# Successful image upload with Nova resource, but receive "This image could not be found" in same resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

**TL;DR**

I successfully upload an image using a Laravel Nova resource. I can see the file name when I ssh into my server and I can see the image path in the corresponding record on my staging database. However, Nova says, "This image could not be found." It also displays a broken image link on the page where I'm serving the image. **How do get the image to display in my staging Nova resource and my staging site?**

**Further Info**

I've deployed a staging site using Laravel Forge. This site is using Laravel Nova to upload images, etc. My goal is to upload those images into the storage directory and access them from `public/storage` using a symlink, per [Laravel Filesystem Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files), on the staging site. (I can do this perfectly well if I run my application locally. I can see the image in Nova and on my local site.)

When I upload an image, it successfully uploads to my server; I can see the file when I ssh into my server. Also, it saves the file path in my staging database: `images/TheJournal/Topics/Testing/Test2.jpg.`

**The Problem In Detail**

When I try to look at the file from my Nova admin panel, I get: "This image could not be found." Clicking on "This image," I'm taken to a blank page with the following url in the search bar: `myDomainName/storage/images/TheJournal/Topics/Testing/Test2.jpg`. Again, if I ssh into my server, I can see the file indeed uploaded to my server. Also, I get a 404 error on the page where I'm loading the image (see Vue.js Template below).

**Vue.js Template**

I'm trying to load the image on the front-end using Article.MainPic, which contains the following path: "images/TheJournal/Topics/Testing/Test2.jpg". I get a 404 error doing it this way.

```
<img class="item" :alt="Article.Title" :src="'/storage/' + Article.MainPic">
```

**filesystems.php**

I'm trying to use 'public'

```
'local' => [
   'driver' => 'local', 
   'root' => storage_path('app'), 
 ],
'public' => [ 
    'driver' => 'local', 
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'), 
    'url' => env('APP_URL')."/storage", 
    'visibility' => 'public', 
 ],
'Root' => [ 
    'driver' => 'local', 
    'root' => public_path(), 
    'url' => env('APP_URL'), 
    'visibility' => 'public', 
 ],
```

**Article.php: Nova Resource**

This is the Nova resource field I use.

```
Avatar::make("Square Pic", "MainPic")
->disk("public")
->path("/images/TheJournal/Topics/Testing") 
->storeAs(function (Request $request) { return $request->MainPic->getClientOriginalName(); }) 
->deletable() 
->hideWhenCreating(),
```

**Gitignore**

This is currently in my gitignore file. Maybe this has something to do with the problem? I don't think so because I can see the storage directory in /public/storage/ when I ssh into my server. When I try to change directory into /public/storage/, it says: `-bash: cd: storage: No such file or directory`

```
/public/hot
/public/storage
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Deleting my `public/storage/` and recreating it using `php artisan storage:link`
- Replacing `disk("public")` with `disk("Root")` in my **Article.php** Nova
  Resource. This saved the image to my public/images directory instead
  of `storage/app/images/`. This allowed my Nova Admin panel and web page
  to display the correct image. No 404 error.
- Replacing `'/storage/'` with `'/'` on my **Vue.js Template**

**Does anybody know what might be going on?**

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this question? I am currently facing the same situation and still haven't found an answer why it works fine on local but fails on the vps even after running `php artisan storgae:link` successfully and with files uploaded correctly.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by running the command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

If that does not work, ensure you `APP_URL` is set correctly in your `.env` file in the root of your application directory.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Comment: adding http solved it for me

Answer (score 5):

after you link the storage

go to .env and delete http://localhost
so your

```
APP_URL=
```

just empty

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel Homestead.
From the root of your project:

1. remove the storage link you have previously created:

   rm public/storage
2. connect to the vagrant and create the sym link from there:

   vagrant ssh
   cd code
   php artisan storage:link

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel Homestead.
From the root of your project:

1. remove the storage link you have previously created:

`rm public/storage`

2. connect to the vagrant and create the sym link from there:

   `vagrant ssh`

   `cd code`

   `php artisan storage:link`